# How to pass context from activity to service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-context

I have an issue, I need to access views in an activity from a service. I thought a good way to do that was to pass the activity context and then use it to access the views. Yet, when i run it, it throws a null error, meaning the object (the view) is null. This is the code, i would like to know how to fix this:

```
public class Purchase extends AppCompatActivity {
   private TextView purchaseAmount;
   private Button but;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
      but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.makePurBut);
      purchaseAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.purchaseAmout);
      Intent i = new Intent(Purchase.this, MyHostApduService.class);
      MyHostApduService myHostApduService = new MyHostApduService(Purchase.this);
      startService(i);
  }
}


public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {
static Context context;
   public MyHostApduService(Context context)
   {
      this.context = context;
   }

   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      textView = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.purchaseAmout);
      but = (Button)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.makePurBut);
      return flags;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm surprised android even lets you create a service inside a nested class like that - were you able to declare it in your manifest?

Answer (score 2):

`Service` has it's own context, and it can't interact with UI directly.

But you can create **bound** service or use `ResultReceiver`. That options described, for example, here: https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297

For example, to create bound service, as shown in the example:

1. Add listener interface:

```
interface Callback {
  void sendMes(Object payload); // or more specific signature
}
```

2. In service:

> ```
>     private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
>
>     public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
>         List<Callback> listeners;
>
>         LocalService getService() {
>             return LocalService.this;
>         }
>         void addListener(Callback listener) {
>              listeners.add(listener);
>         }
>         void removeListener(Callback listener) {
>              listeners.remove(listener);
>         }
>     }
> ```

3. In activity (that implements `Callback`):

> ```
> private LocalService mBoundService;
> private LocalService.LocalBinder mBinder;
>
> private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
>     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
>         mBinder = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service);
>         mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
>         ((LocalService.LocalBinder).addListener(MyActivity.this);
>     }
>
>     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
>         mBoundService = null;
>     } 
> };
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     bindService(new Intent(MyActivity.this, LocalService.class),
>                 mConnection,
>                 Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
>     mIsBound = true;
> }
>
> @Overrride 
> public void sendMes(Object payload) { ... }
>
> @Override
> protected void onDestroy() {  
>  super.onDestroy(); 
>  if (mIsBound) {
>         mBinder.removeListener(this);
>         unbindService(mConnection);
>         mIsBound = false;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve your problem would be to [use LocalBroadcastManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/6623972).

Send a broadcast from Service to Activity, then in onReceive you can manipulate your views within Activity itself.

Make sure to register/unregister a Receiver in onStart/onPause instead of onCreate/onDestroy like inside link.